# Arcus Cotangent implementation in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, math, trigonometry

How can arcus cotangent (arccot) be implemented in swift? 
Which library is necessary to import, i am using Darwin but i cant see it when trying to call ?

Comment: So do you really want to **implement** it? It seem that what you rather want is to use a built-in/library function that computes the arcus cotangent. You can do that by calling the C library function `atan` with the reciprocal of the angle you want to find the arcus cotangent of.

Comment: Just [what have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All mathematical functions from [`<math.h>`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/math.3.html) are available in Swift if you

```
import Darwin
```

(which is automatically imported if you import Foundation or UIKit).

Now the inverse cotangent function is not among these, but you can easily compute it from `atan()` using the relationships (see for example [Inverse trigonometric functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions)):

```
arccot(x) = arctan(1/x)        (for x > 0)
arccot(x) = π + arctan(1/x)    (for x < 0)

arccot(x) = π/2 - atan(x)
```

The first two formulae are numerically better suited for *large* 
(absolute) values
of `x`, and the last one is better for *small* values,
so you could define your `acot()` function as

```
func acot(x : Double) -> Double {
    if x > 1.0 {
        return atan(1.0/x)
    } else if x < -1.0 {
        return M_PI + atan(1.0/x)
    } else {
        return M_PI_2 - atan(x)
    }
}
```

For **Swift 3** replace `M_PI` by `Double.pi`.

Comment: Thanks @Martin R for your detailed answer.  I also tried this but as i am new to iOS i thought there is a library that has this trigonometric function by default as it is with sin , cos , tan , atan ... etc

Answer (score 1):

In Swift 4 (iOS 11, Xcode 9)

After placing `import UIKit`, you can write something like:

```
let fi = atan(y/x)
```

Where x and y of type CGFloat (in my case).

Or you can use others if needed:

```
let abc = acos(y)
```

Math functions work with argument types: Double, Float, CGFloat etc.